# "Use Strict" breaking Javascript function - Why?

Tags: javascript, strict

Adding "use strict" to this function is breaking it. Specifically the inputs I am trying to un-disable are remaining disabled in strict mode. csc_popup_in() and csc_popup_out() functions are defined prior to this one. Thanks in advance for any input.

```
function show_cc(){
    document.getElementById('cc_fade').className='none';

    var cc_inps = document.getElementById('cc_fade').getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(i=0 ; i<cc_inps.length ; i++){
        cc_inps[i].disabled=false;
    }

    document.getElementById('csclnk').onmouseover = function(){csc_popup_in();};
    document.getElementById('csclnk').onmouseout = function(){csc_popup_out();};

    if(document.getElementById('amex').checked){
        document.getElementById('cc_num').maxLength = 15;
        document.getElementById('cc_csc').maxLength = 4;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('cc_num').maxLength = 16;
        document.getElementById('cc_csc').maxLength = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely there's an error reported in your JavaScript console ...

Comment: As Pointy suggested, you should be looking for errors. Part of the benefit of strict mode is that you'll potentially get *more* errors telling you something's wrong in your code. This is a good thing.

Comment: Also, but you have unnecessary anonymous functions. You can directly assign the functions as handlers. For example: `document.getElementById('csclnk').onmouseover = csc_popup_in;`

Comment: +1 for the advice on handlers, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to declare "i" with `var`!!!

Comment: Knew it was something stupid. I am self-taught so my debugging methods are not the best. I will work on getting better with JS console as suggested. THANKS!